How to create a Flow using the Tooling API
I am trying to create a flow using postman, but I am getting this error:
Endpoint Url: https://surveysparrow-1d-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v57.0/tooling/sobjects/Flow
Payload
{
  "Metadata": {
    "apiVersion": 57.0,
    "description": "Flow to send outbound message when contact is created with email abc@gmail.com",
    "interviewLabel": "Contact Created Flow {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}",
    "label": "Contact Created Flow",
    "processType": "AutoLaunchedFlow",
    "status": "Active",
    "start": {
      "locationX": 50,
      "locationY": 50,
      "connector": {
        "targetReference": "decisionElement"
      }
    },
    "decisions": [
      {
        "name": "decisionElement",
        "label": "Check Email",
        "locationX": 200,
        "locationY": 50,
        "defaultConnector": {
          "targetReference": "endElement"
        },
        "rules": [
          {
            "name": "emailRule",
            "conditionLogic": "and",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "leftValueReference": "{!$Record.Email}",
                "operator": "EqualTo",
                "rightValue": {
                  "stringValue": "abc@gmail.com"
                }
              }
            ],
            "connector": {
              "targetReference": "sendOutboundMessage"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "actionCalls": [
      {
        "name": "sendOutboundMessage",
        "label": "Send Outbound Message",
        "locationX": 350,
        "locationY": 50,
        "actionName": "EmailChangedOutboundMessage",
        "actionType": "outboundMessages",
        "connector": {
          "targetReference": "endElement"
        }
      }
    ],
    "stages": [],
    "startElementReference": "decisionElement",

    "variables": [],
    "waits": [],
    "recordCreates": [],
    "recordUpdates": [],
    "recordLookups": [],
    "inputAssignments": [],
    "formulas": [],
    "triggerOrder": 1,
    "triggerType": "RecordAfterSave",
    "object": "Contact"
  },
  "FullName": "Contact_Created_Flow",
  "MasterLabel": "Contact Created Flow"
}

Error
[
    {
        "message": "An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 445882273-751527 (-369038424)",
        "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"
    }
]


Try creating without a 'Master Label'. In my case, I used the SOAP service and got the same error, but when I tried it without the 'Master Label', the creation worked fine.
